# Organizing git branches

Tags: git, branch

I have a large-ish project that I'm working on which uses git as the VCS.  At any given time I'm working on implementing a few features/bugfixes, etc.  For any given feature/bug, It would be nice to create a hierarchy of branches -- e.g.

```
$ git branch
  feature1
       sub-branch1
       sub-branch2
       sub-branch3
  feature2
       sub-brancha
      *sub-branchb  #<--currently checked out
       sub-branchc
  bugfix1
       sub-branch-foo

$ git checkout sub-brancha
$ git branch
  feature1
       sub-branch1
       sub-branch2
       sub-branch3
  feature2
      *sub-brancha  #<--currently checked out
       sub-branchb  
       sub-branchc
  bugfix1
       sub-branch-foo
```

Is it possible to do something like this, or do I need to adopt a more primitive naming scheme?

**EDIT**

To make it slightly more concrete what I'm looking for, if feature1 is a git branch, then in the example above, sub-branch1 would all have been created by `git checkout -b sub-branch1` from the `feature1` branch (which is branched from master). e.g.:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b feature1
$ git checkout -b testing
$ git branch
master
   feature1
     *testing
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b feature2
$ git branch
master
   feature1
      testing
  *feature2
```

Having git branch simply organize branches by where they came from (with a little extra indentation) is probably good enough for my purposes ... Although super bonus points if I can have:

```
$ git branch
  feature1
       testing
  feature2
       testing
  bugfix1
       sub-branch-foo
```

With some way to manage the name-conflict between "feature1/testing" and "feature2/testing"

Comment: Why do you have different sub branches for new feature developments?

Comment: @FatihArslan : Why not?  A feature doesn't just change a single piece of code -- A feature could touch a whole bunch of code, each piece which can be tested/developed separately ... Or I have feature-alpha (stable-ish) and feature-beta (unstable).  Alpha seems to work for me, but beta makes some changes to increase performance ... That's two cases right off the top of my head.  As I see it, the reason to do this is no different than the reason to have branches in the first place.

Comment: What's the question? Are you wondering if you can make branches off of branches, or if you can change the `git branch` output format?

Comment: @AbeVoelker -- I want a better way to organize branches into sub-headings.  If I can easily track where a branch came from (e.g. via a level of indentation in git branch), that would probably be good enough.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a naming schemata like feature1/sub-brancha, feature2/sub-branchb and so on, the slash in the name is not a problem for git. However, the branches will still be handled as normal branches (but I wouldn't know how one could handle subbranches differently). The git branch command will list the branches of course with its full name and not the way it's in the example.

Interestingly, the naming schemata including slashes will create a directory hierarchy in .git/refs/heads/. Maybe that's useful for handling the subbranches with some low level commands?

Comment: *sigh* -- this is what I feared.  Every time I set out to do this I end up forgetting and then the whole scheme goes out the window.  I hoped git could eliminate my disorganized tendencies for me...

Comment: You could write a small tool to enforce your naming scheme. Maybe some aliases can already suffice. Or you can take a look at [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) which goes a bit into this direction (but might not completely be what you need).

Comment: gitflow definitely looks like a step in the right direction.  Thanks for that link.

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that some GUI clients like [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com) group branches when you name them this way (ie. `feature/sub-branch1` and `feature/sub-branch2` become `sub-branch1` and `sub-branch2` grouped under `feature`).

Comment: While this is a good strategy, there is one important point to remember. If you create a branch called feature1, then you cannot create a branch called feature1/sub1. So you have to create feature1/main, and then you can create feature1/sub1. So if you want to either do work under the feature1 branch or to integrate work  into it.

Answer (score 3):

Branches in Git are in fact symbolic refs to a key in Git's object store. To quote the documentation [("What is a branch")](http://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual.html#what-is-a-branch):

> > When we need to be precise, we will use the word "branch" to mean a line of development, and "branch head" (or just "head") to mean a reference to the most recent commit on a branch. In the example above, the branch head named "A" is a pointer to one particular commit, but we refer to the line of three commits leading up to that point as all being part of "branch A".

Git manages only a list of references which are stored in files under `.git/refs`. Those references are simply not designed as a tree-like structure.

I recommend to use a branch naming scheme that conveys the hierarchy.

Another possibility is to write an extension that handles the branch tree for you.

Comment: But, when tracking remotes, it does have a (primitive) tree-like structure...(a branch tracking a remote knows where it came from) -- Why can't a branch keep track of where it came from locally?

Comment: I guess the creators of Git wanted to keep it as simple as possible. Incorporating a tree structure for branches would complicate the design. Since branches CAN be derived from other branches it's no problem to organize branches in a decent naming scheme. Then, however, the interpretation of the tree is up to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I've personally used [this](http://zanematthew.com/git-nested-branches-growth/) approach in earlier versions of Git, but it seems that nested branches are no longer supported in version 1.8+.

It was also nice to see the UI support in Git Tower.

[image]